# Space Delimited Text File as Input into a Compiled DOS Fortran Program

Tags: file, text, space, delimited

I have a very powerful dos based program written in Fortran and last updated in +- 2001.

The input files for this program must be such that each character must be in a certain position when fed in.

If one character or number is out of place it will not work or will give the incorrect output.

Is there some kind of software available to more easily enable one to format the text input data?(more easily than what I do now which is use a plain Text editor)

Is there perhaps a more advanced text editor that will assist with this matter?

Answer (score 0):

TextDistil (www.textdistil.com) is intended to help with this kind of problem.  Alternatively you could write a perl/python script to parse the input and ensure each line is in the correct format.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TextDistil so obviously a little biased ;-)